# Cascaded drop down not working in IE alone

Tags: list, jquery, spservices, cascading

I have created a 3 level cascading drop down in SP2010 list.

The cascading drop down is working perfectly in Firefox and Mozilla but in IE,the drop down values from level 2 are not displayed.

Can someone help me on what could be the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Which version of spservices you are using for cascading?

Comment: @user2264989 SPServices 0.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint renders dropdowns differently in Internet Explorer depending on whether they have fewer than 20 options or 20+ options. (In Firefox, Chrome, and other browsers, SharePoint doesn’t give us this “benefit”.)

You can use SPComplexToSimpleDropdown function as below:
How Does It Work?

The SPComplexToSimpleDropdown function works like this:

- When the function is first called, it finds the dropdown control for the specified column name. If the control cannot be found and debug mode is enabled, an error is shown.
- If the dropdown for the specified column is not a complex dropdown, we do nothing. This might be the case if the number of available options has decreased to fewer than 20, for instance.
- The input element for the complex dropdown contains an attribute called choices which contains all of the available values and their IDs in one long vertical bar (“|”) separated string, e.g., “(None)|0|Alabama|18|Alaska|114|Alberta|16|Arizona|8|Arkansas|98|...“
- The function takes that string of values and builds up a simple select (the kind you are most likely familiar with) and prepends it to the table detail cell (TD) which contains the complex dropdown. The new simple select will have its id  set to "SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_" + opt.columnName for easy selection later, if needed.
- Next we hide the original dropdown.
- Finally, we attach to the change event for the simple select we have created. When a change occurs, we set the value of the complex dropdown to match the selected option and trigger a click event on the small dropdown image image, thus initiating some of SharePoint’s native script to handle the change.  By maintaining the complex dropdown “as is”, we can ensure that the proper value is stored in the list when the changes are committed.

Note that if the function fails for whatever reason, you should still be left with a working form.

**Syntax**

```
$().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
columnName: "",
completefunc: null,
debug: true});
```

**columnName**

The DisplayName of the column in the form

completefunc

If specified, the completefunc will be called each time there is a change to columnName. Potential uses for the completefunc: consistent default formatting overrides, additional lookup customizations, image manipulations, etc. You can pass your completefunc in either of these two ways:

```
completefunc: function() {  ...do something...},
```

Eg:

```
 $().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
        columnName: "Application",
        completefunc: null,
            debug: true
        });
                    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
                                    relationshipList: "Service",
                                    relationshipListParentColumn: "Applications",
                                    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                                    parentColumn: "Application",
                                    childColumn: "Service",
                                    simpleChild: true,
                                    debug: true
                    });
                    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
                                    relationshipList: "Area",
                                    relationshipListParentColumn: "Applications",
                                    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                                    parentColumn: "Application",
                                    childColumn: "Area",
                                    simpleChild: true,
                                    debug: true
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked in IE with the additional script :)